# Separation of a String into Individual Words (Python)

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

So I have this code here:

```
#assign a string to variable
x = "example text"
#create set to store separated words
xset = []
#create base word
xword = ""
for letter in x:
    if letter == " ":
        #add word
        xset.append(xword)
        #add space
        xset.append(letter)
        #reset base word
    else:
        #add letter
        xword = xword + letter
        #back to line 9
#print set with separated words
print xset
```

So pretty self explanatory, the for function looks at each letter in `x`, and if it isn't a space it adds it to `xword` (Imagine it like `xword = "examp" + "l"`, that would make `xword = "exampl"`). If it is a space, it adds `xword` and a space to the set, and resets `xword`.

My issue comes to the fact that the word `"text"` is not being included in the final set. When this code is run, and the set is printed, it gives this:`['example', ' ']

So why isn't the `"text"` appearing in the set?

Comment: In your loop, you only add a word when you hit a space. There is no space after your last word, so the last word doesn't get added. Try adding `xword` to your list (it is a list, not a set) after the loop finishes.

Comment: I guess you are doing this as part of a lesson. In that case, it makes sense. Otherwise: `xset = x.split()`

Comment: `x.split()` is good but if you want to keep the space in the list, do
`re.split("( )", x)`

Comment: `import re` -> `re.split(r'(\W+)', x)`

Answer (score 1):

Because when your code reaches the space in `x` it appends `xword`. But this only happens when it reaches a space. As there are no spaces after text, the final result is not appended to `xset` Also, you were not resetting `xword`:

```
#assign a string to variable
x = "example text"
#create set to store separated words
xset = []
#create base word
xword = ""
for letter in x:
    if letter == " ":
        #add word
        xset.append(xword)
        #add space
        xset.append(letter)
        #reset base word
        xword = ""
    else:
        #add letter
        xword = xword + letter
        #back to line 9
#print set with separated words
xset.append(xword)
print xset
```

Output:

```
['example', ' ', 'text']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one more append after the loop to add the last word

```
#assign a string to variable
x = "example text"
#create set to store separated words
xset = []
#create base word
xword = ""
for letter in x:
    if letter == " ":
        #add word
        xset.append(xword)
        #add space
        xset.append(letter)
        #reset base word
    else:
        #add letter
        xword = xword + letter
        #back to line 9
xset.append(xword)
#print set with separated words
print xset
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use string.split(). This command will return list of word in your string. Here is documentation on it: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

If your values are space separated do something like this:

```
r.split()
Out[26]: ['some', 'text', 'here']
```

If your seperator different from space you can specify it like this:

```
s.split(',')
Out[21]: ['some', 'text', 'here']
```